# select info of clients from DB and store into vector

Tags: c++, sql-server-2005

okay so I need to know how to select all people from a Database age 21 and store their information into a vector so that I can render that into a list inside my program

```
SELECT Name, Age, State FROM ACCOUNT_DBF.dbo.CLIENTLIST Where Name=tom

while( qry->Fetch() )
{    
    Name    =    qry->GetInt("Name");
    Age    =    qry->GetInt("Age");
    State    =    qry->GetInt("State");
}
```

I have something like this above for getting to information of one person
I know this works for selecting info from one person but for selecting all people age 21 I don't understand how to store that into a vector what do I do after fetching I created the following structure

```
struct CURRENT_MEMBER
{
    TCHAR Name[MAX_NAME];
    int age;
    int state;
};
```

I need it to store in the vector like this

Tom 21 50

to be able to render all clients into a scrolling list box

```
jane 21 15
max 21 25
Tom 21 50
sara 21 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an array.
Some more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkxxx2e.aspx).
Comment with details if you'd like a more specific code example.

```
CURRENT_MEMBER Members [MAX_MEMBER_COUNT];

for (int i=0; i<nMemberCount; i++)
{
    Members[i].Name= <info from DB>;
    Members[i].age= <info from DB>;
    Members[i].state= <info from DB>;
}
```

Comment: how do I find MAX_MEMBER_COUNT do I do this via sql or c++ I'm not sure about that

Comment: @420 I assume you invented the value for `MAX_NAME` as the constant maximum length for a person's name. `MAX_MEMBER_COUNT` would be a similar constant that you could assign to whatever you wanted: e.g. `const int MAX_MEMBER_COUNT=50` or something like that. You just have to make sure the value is constant for an array declared like this.

Comment: I will check this as the answer if you can explain how I find the amount of members returned in the sql statement

Comment: @420 Also, if you need to be able to make this work without knowing the absolute length of the array (vector), then there's a different approach that uses pointers and dynamic memory allocation to implement your array. There's a good code example of this in the article that I linked for you.

Comment: yea I want to select all members age 21 so I don't know how many it will find

Comment: @420 My thought is, the `qry` object should have a property that provides the number of results returned by the query. Have you checked into the available properties of this object? I don't know them off the top of my head, but most development environments will give you a drop-down list of available operations if you type `qry->`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (if you really want to use a vector)?

```
public class Member
{
    TCHAR Name[MAX_NAME];
    int age;
    int state;

    //for vector::push_back to work (pass by value)
    public Member(const Member& other)
    {
        Name = new TCHAR[MAX_NAME];

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NAME; i++)
        {
            Name[i] = other.Name[i];
        }
        age = other.age;
        state = other.state;
    }

    public Member(TCHAR ar[],int a, int st)
    {
        Name = new TCHAR[MAX_NAME];

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NAME; i++)
        {
            //careful!
            Name[i] = ar[i];
        }
        age = a;
        state = st;
    }
}
```

....

```
   vector<Member> yourVector = new vector<Member>();

   while( qry->Fetch() )
   {    
       yourVector.push_back(new Member(qry->GetInt("Name"), 
          qry->GetInt("Age"), qry->GetInt("State"));
   }
```